# create pdf from binary data in java

Tags: java, pdf, java-io

I'm getting this string from a web service.

"**JVBERi0xLjQKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovR3JvdXAgPDwvVHlwZSAvR3JvdXAgL1MgL1RyYW5zcGFyZW5jeSAvQ1MgL0RldmljZVJHQj4"**

It is supposed to be a pdf file, i tried this library **pdfbox** from apache, but it writes the content as a text inside the pdf. I've tried with **ByteArrayInputStream** but the pdf created is not valid, corrupted, this is some of the code i've wrote.

```
public void escribePdf(String texto, String rutaSalida) throws IOException{

    byte[] biteToRead = texto.getBytes();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(biteToRead );
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new  BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(rutaSalida))));
    int c;
    while((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        out.writeByte(c);
    }
    out.close();
    is.close();

}
```

Comment: That string may well be a valid pdf file in binary but you have to know what encoding it was made in. Java uses UTF-16 by default but not all encodings will be the same value.

Comment: The pdf is created with php.

Comment: Don't use a DataOutputStream.  Write directly to the BufferedOutputStream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is Base64 encoded (most probably UTF-8) data, you must decode it before using; such as:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
```

...

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(biteToRead);
```

....

Edit:
For java >= 1.8, use:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(biteToRead);
```

Answer (score 3):

[JDK 8]

Imports:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Base64;
```

Code:

```
// Get bytes, most important part
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("JVBERi0xLjQKMyAwIG9iago8P...");
// Write to file
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
os.write(bytes);
os.close();
```

Comment: This one works for me. Thanks Cordova +1 from my side.

Comment: Is there a way for `output.pdf` to exist, in-memory? (rather than get written to a file?

Answer (score 2):

Your string is definitively base 64 encoded. It translates to

```
%PDF-1.4
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group <</Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRG
```

which isnt a full pdf file by itself which leads me to belive you have something wrong with the way your reading the data from the server.

As of java 6 they added a base 64 converter outside the sun packages.

```
byte [] bytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverte.parseBase64Binary(texto);
new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```